# Esign field in Webform

Tags: 7, webforms

I am attempting to add a signature field with validation to a webform.  The validation fields show up, the signature field seems to be there (cursor changes to +) but no field for signature is there.

Esign's documentation says to "
    Did you set the field to display?
    Does your CSS allow the field to display?
"
I'm suspecting that one of these may be my issue.  However, I have no idea where to set the field to display.  I should note that I added the esign field by adding the field in "form components" and not "form builder" as the field esign did not show up in the "form builder" tab.

Any help would be most welcome!

This is for Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the field to display in this page:
admin/config/content/webform

For whatever reason the e-sign field doesnt appear for me under `form builder` it appears when i go to `form components` under `type` there should be an option called `E-sign`.

Comment: The E-sign field does not appear as a type of form component in Drupal 7 Webform module. Am I missing something?